# Why my app run twice?

Tags: android, runtime

My app works well befor but now its run then after a seconds run again.
first : show splashactivity then login activity

Here my project's codes :

**Manifest :**

```
 <application
        android:name=".Adjust.GlobalApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Transparet">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.GetActiveCodeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />

        <service
            android:name=".Services.RestService"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.WalletRechargeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.BillsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.TransferActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.BuyChargeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.TransferConfirmationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.RegisterEventActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.CharityActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.AddGroupTransferActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.ScanQrActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.InvitationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.BuyInternetActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

        <activity android:name=".Activity.SetPayPassActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.PaymentResult">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action." />

                <data
                    android:host="example"
                    android:scheme="example" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity.UpdateActvity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.WebView" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.MagicMessage" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.ContactActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

**SplashActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.status));
        }

        linearLayout_init = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_init);
        //animate login view
        linearLayout_init.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Animation animTranslate  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashActivity.this, R.anim.translate);
        animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                linearLayout_init.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Animation animFade  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                linearLayout_init.startAnimation(animFade);
            }
        });
        ImageView imgLogo = findViewById(R.id.img_kipologo);
        imgLogo.startAnimation(animTranslate);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                getSharedPreference();

            }
        }, 3000);

    }

    public void getSharedPreference(){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("example", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String isLogin = sharedPreferences.getString("mobileN", null);

        if(isLogin != null )
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        } else {
            Intent myIntent;
            myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
```

I'm using Preference because of that if user logined befor app doesn't
go to login activity again

In my debug it seems that SpalshActivity Runs many time and I don't know why!

Comment: Use only `finish()` , it'll take its reference itself. Also instead of `String isLogin = sharedPreferences.getString("mobileN", null);`  use  `boolean isLogin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("mobileN", false);`

Answer (score 0):

Within this thread,

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getSharedPreference();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

**Problem:**
You are currently having a delay in milliseconds of 3000. After your `getSharedPreference()` method is executed, your application is proceeding to the following activity through the usage of an intent. However, in the same time, your splashScreen Activity is trying to maintain its state in the foreground because it's forcefully waiting for 3 sec before doing whatever it has to do, that's why you are ending up with SplashScreen Activity been called/displayed more than one.

**Fix:**
One way to get around this is to not have any delay and just execute your getSharedPreference() method in a thread with no timer.

For example: you can use:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  //Do work here
                }
            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
```

**Side Note:**
You do not have to forcefully finish your SplashScreen Activity using `SplashActivity.this.finish();`. The activity will be destroyed on its own when necessary. Only if you have memory issues and you wanted to immediately free up some spaces, but that's not the case in this example.

Comment: Splash screen should always be finished after moving to next screen, so when user comes back by doing back presses, Splash won't open again. Also I think how you explained `postDelayed` method, is not proper.